# XML Twig doesn't indent new added elements?

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, xml-twig

relevant part of the XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<key name="home">
        <entry name="default">zzzzz</entry>
        <key name="ffffff"></key>
        <key name="plugin">
                <key name="pst">
                        <entry name="enable">true</entry>
                </key>
        </key>
        <key name="hover">
                <key name="doze">
                        <key name="eventmanager">
                                <key name="types"></key>
                        </key>
                        <key name="ips">
                                <key name="proto">
                                        <key name="dos">
                                                <key name="dop"></key>
                                        </key>
                                </key>
                        </key>
                </key>
        </key>
.
.
.
```

my code:

```
#!/root/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;


my $tree = XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented', keep_spaces => 1);

$tree->parsefile(shift);
my $msg =<<'MSG';
<key name="absy">
 <entry name="msg"></entry>
 <entry name="title"></entry>
</key>
MSG

my $client_plugin = XML::Twig::Elt->new( key => { name => 'client' } )->set_inner_xml($msg);

$client_plugin->paste(last_child => $tree->first_elt(sub {  $_[0]->tag =~ m/key/ and $_[0]->att('name') =~ m/plugin/i }));

$tree->print;
```

the issue is that the added element appears in one single line, and not really indented like the rest of the elements.
I also tried `$tree->print(pretty_print => 'indented')` with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `XML::Twig::Elt` module is discarding insignificant whitespace from your `inner_html` call.

Meanwhile, you have specified `keep_spaces => 1`, for the `XML::Twig` module so it is retaining the (lack of) spaces as they are.

Remove `keep_spaces => 1` and it should work for you.

**Update**

You may want to look at this code that does the same thing as your own program but uses an XPath step as a condition instead of the less-readable anonymous subroutine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $tree = XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => 'indented');
$tree->parsefile(shift);

my $msg = <<'MSG';
<key name="absy">
    <entry name="msg"/>
    <entry name="title"/>
</key>
MSG

my $client_plugin = XML::Twig::Elt->new( key => { name => 'client' } );
$client_plugin->set_inner_xml($msg);

my $plugin = $tree->first_elt('key[@name="plugin"]');
$client_plugin->paste(last_child => $plugin);

$tree->print;
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<key name="home">
  <entry name="default">zzzzz</entry>
  <key name="ffffff"></key>
  <key name="plugin">
    <key name="pst">
      <entry name="enable">true</entry>
    </key>
    <key name="client">
      <key name="absy">
        <entry name="msg"/>
        <entry name="title"/>
      </key>
    </key>
  </key>
  <key name="hover">
    <key name="doze">
      <key name="eventmanager">
        <key name="types"></key>
      </key>
      <key name="ips">
        <key name="proto">
          <key name="dos">
            <key name="dop"></key>
          </key>
        </key>
      </key>
    </key>
  </key>
</key>
```

Comment: to be closer to the original code, you can also have a regexp on the attribute value: `my $plugin = $tree->first_elt('key[@name=~ /plugin/i]');` - BTW, that's some seriously ugly XML you have here!